# seeing if gps coordinates fall within a range of coordinates in R

Tags: r, gps, geocode

I have a list of GPS coordinates and I want to see if they fall in a certain range of GPS coordinates. My list is about 6000 points, but I have 44000 ranges. These GPS coordinates are based on street addresses so I was thinking to narrow my ranges by street name first and then seeing if the coordinates fall within the subset of ranges, which are street blocks. Otherwise I would have 6000x44000 searches and that would take forever. Anyone have any idea on what would be the most efficient way to do this? I'm completely new to R and coding in general so I'm have no idea where to start.

Comment: I also have the street addresses for my points, but the problem is that street name data isn't always accurate. Something like Briargrove St. would be Briar Grove St in the other dataset

Comment: Coul you add a small example data set? Use `dput(yourData)` and copy and paste the result in here.